# Boto3 getting Error "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, pip, boto3

```
import boto3
import os

os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = "us-east-1"


def get_secret_value():
    
    """Gets the value of a secret.

    Version (if defined) is used to retrieve a particular version of
    the secret.

    """

    secrets_client = boto3.clie("secretsmanager", region_name = "us-east-1")
    kwargs = {'SecretId': "DBName"}
   # if version is not None:
   #     kwargs['VersionStage'] = version
    response = secrets_client.get_secret_value(**kwargs)
    print(response)
    return response

get_secret_value()
```

This is the sample designed which helps in retrieving the secrets which provides me a fatal error of unable to locate credentials.

Comment: Where and how are you running the code? How did you configure your credentials?

Comment: I am running my code via cmd and I configure my credentials in aws s3 for secretManager

Comment: You need to configure IAM access keys to use the AWS API. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html

Comment: Hello, I have that Access keys as well.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the full error message you're seeing, as well as include the code you're running, not an version of with with a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this code on an Amazon EC2 instance, then you should **assign an IAM Role** to the instance. Credentials will be automatically provided to your program via boto3.

If you are running this code on your own computer, then you should run the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command and provide your Access Key and Secret Key. It will store those credentials in the `~/.aws/credentials` file and boto3 will retrieve them automatically.